# How to preserve localized messages when dumping a generation in WInDBG using SOSEX (and logging the output with .logopen)?

Tags: windbg

I use sosex `dumpgen 0 -live` command and at the same time log the session using the `.logopen` command.

The dump file is created from the following simple C# program (when it waits for input):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string[] s_strings =
        {
            "good morning",
            "good\r\nmorning",
            "good\nmorning.",
            "bonne journée",
            "bonne\r\njournée",
            "bonne\njournée",
            "добрый день",
            "добрый\r\nдень",
            "добрый\nдень"
        };

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            foreach (var s in s_strings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I inspect the log the russian string **добрый день** is shown as "?????? ????". When I run the command without logging, the CDB.exe debugger prints the same on the console (which is capable to display unicode).

It is the same in WinDBG.

Notice, that the french **bonne journée** is displayed just fine. Most likely because of the Windows-1252 encoding used by the debugger. Which is fine for latin, but not so fine for russian, for example.

I want to see all the localized messages in the dump correctly, i.e. I want the debugger to use the Unicode or UTF8 encoding and not Windows-1252.

How do I do it?

Comment: This is probably a bug in SOSEX. I'll look into it asap, which may be a few days.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking forward.

Comment: `.logopen` (ASCII, ANSI) or `.logopen /u` for Unicode format?

Comment: It is not about `.logopen`. The `!dumpgen` command produces ANSI text instead of Unicode or UTF8 or something configurable.

Comment: The Console font should be changed to Lucida Console, raster fonts are no good. Hmm, interesting. I ran the `!dumpgen` command inside WinDbg and at CDB command prompt using a console capable to display both russian and french (changed its font) and it showed question marks. Hence I supposed `.logopen` is irrelevant. I will check the /u flag.

Comment: @SteveJohnson: ping. Check my answer before you invest too much time...

Answer (score 0):

Using `.logopen /u` for Unicode output and opening the file as UCS-2 Little Endian in Notepad++ solved the issue for me.

Relevant lines:

```
020b317c   70e2e918        36   System.String   STRVAL="добрый день"
020b31a0   70e2e918        38   System.String   STRVAL="добрый

день"
020b31c8   70e2e918        36   System.String   STRVAL="добрый
день"
```

I copy/pasted your code to a new VS2015 Console Application, compiled for .NET 4.6.1, AnyCPU and ran the Debug build.

Debugging with SOSex 4.5.0.783 and WinDbg 6.2.9200.16384 on Windows 7 x64.

Console output with Raster font:

[image: Console output - Raster font]

Console output with Lucida font:

[image: Console output - Lucida font]

Complete output of the command:

```
Opened log file 'c:\tmp\unicode.log'
0:004> !dumpgen 0 -live
Object     MT            Size   Name
---------------------------------------------------
020b1018   006056b8        10   **** FREE ****
020b1024   70e2ea60        84   System.Exception
020b1078   70e2ebb4        84   System.OutOfMemoryException
020b10cc   70e2ebf8        84   System.StackOverflowException
020b1120   70e2ec3c        84   System.ExecutionEngineException
020b1174   70e2ec80        84   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
020b11c8   70e2ec80        84   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
020b121c   70e2ecb8        12   System.Object
020b1228   70e2e918        14   System.String   STRVAL=
020b1238   70e2ed54        28   System.SharedStatics
020b1254   70e2e918       170   System.String   STRVAL="E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\DumpGenUnicodeIssue\DumpgenUnicodeIssue\bin\Debug\"
020b1300   70e2e918       230   System.String   STRVAL="E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\DumpGenUnicodeIssue\DumpgenUnicodeIssue\bin\Debug\DumpgenUnicodeIssue.exe.Config"
020b13e8   70e2edd0       112   System.AppDomain
020b1458   70e2e918        22   System.String   STRVAL="true"
020b1470   70e2e918        78   System.String   STRVAL="PARTIAL_TRUST_VISIBLE_ASSEMBLIES"
020b14c0   70e2f184        68   System.AppDomainSetup
020b1504   70e2e918       216   System.String   STRVAL="E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\DumpGenUnicodeIssue\DumpgenUnicodeIssue\bin\Debug\DumpgenUnicodeIssue.exe"
020b15dc   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL=".config"
020b15f8   70e2f320        16   System.Char[]
020b1608   70e2e918        60   System.String   STRVAL="DumpgenUnicodeIssue.exe"
020b1644   70e2f46c        84   System.String[]
020b1698   70e2e918       170   System.String   STRVAL="E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\DumpGenUnicodeIssue\DumpgenUnicodeIssue\bin\Debug\"
020b1744   70e2e918        74   System.String   STRVAL="DumpgenUnicodeIssue.exe.config"
020b1790   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="RELPATH"
020b17ac   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL=";"
020b17bc   70e2e918        38   System.String   STRVAL="DYNAMIC_BASE"
020b17e4   70e2e918        44   System.String   STRVAL="PRIVATE_BINPATH"
020b1810   70e2e918        46   System.String   STRVAL="SHADOW_COPY_DIRS"
020b1840   70e2e918        34   System.String   STRVAL="CACHE_BASE"
020b1864   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="APPBASE"
020b1880   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="DEV_PATH"
020b18a0   70e2e918        38   System.String   STRVAL="DISALLOW_APP"
020b18c8   70e2e918        58   System.String   STRVAL="CODE_DOWNLOAD_DISABLED"
020b1904   70e2e918        58   System.String   STRVAL="DISALLOW_APP_REDIRECTS"
020b1940   70e2e918        64   System.String   STRVAL="DISALLOW_APP_BASE_PROBING"
020b1980   70e2e918        52   System.String   STRVAL="FORCE_CACHE_INSTALL"
020b19b4   70e2e918        50   System.String   STRVAL="BINPATH_PROBE_ONLY"
020b19e8   70e2e918        44   System.String   STRVAL="APP_CONFIG_FILE"
020b1a14   70e2e918        44   System.String   STRVAL="APP_CONFIG_BLOB"
020b1a40   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="APP_NAME"
020b1a60   70e2e918        42   System.String   STRVAL="MACHINE_CONFIG"
020b1a8c   70e2e918        56   System.String   STRVAL="config\machine.config"
020b1ac4   70e2e918        36   System.String   STRVAL="HOST_CONFIG"
020b1ae8   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="false"
020b1b00   70e2e918       106   System.String   STRVAL="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"
020b1b6c   70e2e918       148   System.String   STRVAL="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config"
020b1c00   70e2e918        78   System.String   STRVAL="NetFx40_TimeSpanLegacyFormatMode"
020b1c50   70e2e918        70   System.String   STRVAL="NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy"
020b1c98   70e2e918        82   System.String   STRVAL="NetFx45_LegacyManagedDeflateStream"
020b1cec   70e2f664        36   System.Security.PermissionSet
020b1d10   70e2f7ac        20   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePEFileHandle
020b1d24   70e2f8b8        32   System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory
020b1d44   70e2f568        40   System.Security.Policy.Evidence
020b1d6c   70a04960        48   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]]
020b1d9c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1db8   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1dd4   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1df0   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e0c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e28   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e44   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e60   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e7c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1e98   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1eb4   70e301c8        12   System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[[System.Type, mscorlib]]
020b1ec0   70e30214        52   System.Type[]
020b1ef4   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f10   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f2c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f48   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f64   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f80   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1f9c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1fb8   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1fd4   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b1ff0   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b200c   70e30764       300   System.Int32[]
020b2138   70e2ecb8        12   System.Object
020b2144   70e30764        24   System.Int32[]
020b215c   70e30f0c        60   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]][]
020b2198   70e30764        40   System.Int32[]
020b21c0   70e30f0c       124   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]][]
020b223c   70e30764        80   System.Int32[]
020b228c   70e30f0c       284   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]][]
020b23a8   70e310ec        44   System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock
020b23d4   70e31134        28   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
020b23f0   70e31218        16   System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory
020b2400   70e31278        16   System.Security.Policy.Evidence+EvidenceLockHolder
020b2410   70e312c0        12   System.Security.HostSecurityManager
020b241c   70e314a8        24   System.AppDomainManager
020b2434   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2450   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b246c   70e31624        56   System.RuntimeType[]
020b24a4   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b24c0   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b24dc   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b24f8   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2514   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2530   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b254c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2568   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2584   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b25a0   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b25bc   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b25d8   70a04a40        48   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.RuntimeType, mscorlib],[System.RuntimeType, mscorlib]]
020b2608   70e30764        56   System.Int32[]
020b2640   70e31904       188   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.RuntimeType, mscorlib],[System.RuntimeType, mscorlib]][]
020b26fc   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2718   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2734   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2750   70e319b8        12   System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[[System.RuntimeType, mscorlib]]
020b275c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2778   70e31a6c        12   System.Attribute[]
020b2784   70e31adc        32   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule
020b27a4   70e2e918        58   System.String   STRVAL="RFLCT.InvalidFieldFail"
020b27e0   70e2e918        56   System.String   STRVAL="RFLCT.InvalidPropFail"
020b2818   70e31c38       180   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord[]
020b28cc   70e2dd04        68   System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute[]
020b2910   70e31e9c        12   System.Reflection.__Filters
020b291c   70e31ef4        32   System.Reflection.TypeFilter
020b293c   70e31ef4        32   System.Reflection.TypeFilter
020b295c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2978   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2994   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b29b0   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b29cc   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b29e8   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a04   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a20   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a3c   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a58   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a74   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2a90   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2aac   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2ac8   70e31134        28   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
020b2ae4   70e1e608        48   System.RuntimeMethodInfoStub
020b2b14   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2b30   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b2b4c   70e31554        16   System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
020b2b5c   70e2e918        70   System.String   STRVAL=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"
020b2ba4   70e2e918        54   System.String   STRVAL="FrameworkDisplayName"
020b2bdc   70e2e918        54   System.String   STRVAL=".NET Framework 4.6.1"
020b2c14   70e2d718        12   System.__Filters
020b2c20   70e2d77c        32   System.Reflection.MemberFilter
020b2c40   70e2d77c        32   System.Reflection.MemberFilter
020b2c60   70e2d77c        32   System.Reflection.MemberFilter
020b2c80   70e2d7cc        12   System.Reflection.Missing
020b2c8c   70e30214        12   System.Type[]
020b2c98   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="*"
020b2ca8   70e2d54c        84   System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache
020b2cfc   70e31adc        32   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule
020b2d1c   70e2b0fc        28   System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache+MemberInfoCache`1[[System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo, mscorlib]]
020b2d38   70e2b684        28   System.Text.UTF8Encoding
020b2d54   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="�"
020b2d64   70e3211c        16   System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
020b2d74   70e3216c        16   System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
020b2d84   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="chars"
020b2d9c   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="bytes"
020b2db4   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="byteCount"
020b2dd4   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="charCount"
020b2df4   70e287c4        23   System.Boolean[]
020b2e0c   70e2afdc        56   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo
020b2e44   70e29604        28   System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache+MemberInfoCache`1[[System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo, mscorlib]]
020b2e60   70e29644        16   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo[]
020b2e70   70e29474        60   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
020b2eac   70e29644        16   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo[]
020b2ebc   70e29474        60   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
020b2ef8   70e29644        28   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo[]
020b2f14   70e2b13c        16   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo[]
020b2f24   70e2b22c        20   System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2+Table[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo[], mscorlib]]
020b2f38   70e2f46c        40   System.String[]
020b2f60   70e2b26c        40   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo[][]
020b2f88   70e29044        44   System.Signature
020b2fb4   70e31624        12   System.RuntimeType[]
020b2fc0   70e2915c        12   System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[]
020b2fcc   70e2915c        12   System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[]
020b2fd8   70e29044        44   System.Signature
020b3004   70e31624        12   System.RuntimeType[]
020b3010   70e2ed0c        16   System.Object[]
020b3020   70e29044        44   System.Signature
020b304c   70e31624        16   System.RuntimeType[]
020b305c   70e2ed0c        16   System.Object[]
020b306c   70e2d0f0        12   System.IntPtr
020b3078   70e2dd04        16   System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute[]
020b3088   70e2e918        38   System.String   STRVAL="good morning"
020b30b0   70e2e918        40   System.String   STRVAL="good

morning"
020b30d8   70e2e918        40   System.String   STRVAL="good
morning."
020b3100   70e2e918        40   System.String   STRVAL="bonne journée"
020b3128   70e2e918        42   System.String   STRVAL="bonne

journée"
020b3154   70e2e918        40   System.String   STRVAL="bonne
journée"
020b317c   70e2e918        36   System.String   STRVAL="добрый день"
020b31a0   70e2e918        38   System.String   STRVAL="добрый

день"
020b31c8   70e2e918        36   System.String   STRVAL="добрый
день"
020b31ec   70e2f46c        48   System.String[]
020b321c   70e2e918        84   System.String   STRVAL="-----------------------------------"
020b3270   70e2e918        64   System.String   STRVAL="Press any key to exit ..."
020b32b0   70e31f50        32   System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
020b32d0   70e3211c        16   System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
020b32e0   70e3216c        16   System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
020b32f0   70e23ab0        16   System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission
020b3300   70e20634        12   System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
020b330c   70e27910        36   System.Security.Util.TokenBasedSet
020b3330   70e279a0        32   System.Security.PermissionTokenFactory
020b3350   70e279d8        80   System.Security.PermissionToken[]
020b33a0   70e32298        52   System.Collections.Hashtable
020b33d4   70e32388        96   System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
020b3434   70e32298        52   System.Collections.Hashtable
020b3468   70e32388        96   System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
020b34c8   70e278b0        20   System.Security.PermissionToken
020b34dc   70e177ec        28   Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native+InputRecord
020b34f8   70e31f50        32   System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
020b3518   70e3211c        16   System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
020b3528   70e3216c        16   System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
020b3538   70e2ecb8        12   System.Object
020b3544   70e31f50        32   System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
020b3564   70e321e4        20   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle
020b3578   70e321e4        20   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle
020b358c   70e17834        28   System.IO.__ConsoleStream
020b35a8   70e17aa4        20   System.IO.Stream+NullStream
020b35bc   70e333e8        60   System.IO.StreamWriter
020b35f8   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="encoding"
020b3618   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="stream"
020b3634   70e2f320        16   System.Char[]
020b3644   70e173a8        28   System.Text.EncoderNLS
020b3660   70e2f320       524   System.Char[]
020b386c   70e335fc       526   System.Byte[]
020b3a7c   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="charIndex"
020b3a9c   70e1792c        24   System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter
020b3ab4   70e2f508        52   System.Threading.Thread
020b3ae8   70e324e4        72   System.Globalization.CultureInfo
020b3b30   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL=","
020b3b40   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="1"
020b3b50   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="."
020b3b60   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="%"
020b3b70   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="0"
020b3b80   70e2e918        90   System.String   STRVAL="Invariant Language (Invariant Country)"
020b3bdc   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="iv"
020b3bf0   70e2e918        50   System.String   STRVAL="Invariant Language"
020b3c24   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="IV"
020b3c38   70e2e918        48   System.String   STRVAL="Invariant Country"
020b3c68   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="+"
020b3c78   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="-"
020b3c88   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="2"
020b3c98   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="3"
020b3ca8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="4"
020b3cb8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="5"
020b3cc8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="6"
020b3cd8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="7"
020b3ce8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="8"
020b3cf8   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="9"
020b3d08   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="NaN"
020b3d1c   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="Infinity"
020b3d3c   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="-Infinity"
020b3d5c   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="‰"
020b3d6c   70e2e918        16   System.String   STRVAL="¤"
020b3d7c   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="XDR"
020b3d90   70e2e918        68   System.String   STRVAL="International Monetary Fund"
020b3dd4   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="AM"
020b3de8   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="PM"
020b3dfc   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="HH:mm:ss"
020b3e1c   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="HH:mm"
020b3e34   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="hh:mm tt"
020b3e54   70e2e918        22   System.String   STRVAL="H:mm"
020b3e6c   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="h:mm tt"
020b3e88   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="Latn;"
020b3ea0   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="IVL"
020b3eb4   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="IVC"
020b3ec8   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="ivl"
020b3edc   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="ivc"
020b3ef0   70e2e918        40   System.String   STRVAL="0409:00000409"
020b3f18   70e2e918       114   System.String   STRVAL="System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\RegionMapping"
020b3f8c   70e32754        24   System.Version
020b3fa4   70e32720       308   System.Globalization.CultureData
020b40d8   70e2f46c        52   System.String[]
020b410c   70e30764        16   System.Int32[]
020b411c   70e30764        16   System.Int32[]
020b412c   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b413c   70e2f46c        28   System.String[]
020b4158   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b4168   70e30764        16   System.Int32[]
020b4178   70e32808       104   System.Globalization.CalendarData[]
020b41e0   70e2e918        50   System.String   STRVAL="Gregorian Calendar"
020b4214   70e2e918        34   System.String   STRVAL="MM/dd/yyyy"
020b4238   70e2e918        34   System.String   STRVAL="yyyy-MM-dd"
020b425c   70e2e918        50   System.String   STRVAL="dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"
020b4290   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="yyyy MMMM"
020b42b0   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="MMMM dd"
020b42cc   70e2e918        22   System.String   STRVAL="A.D."
020b42e4   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="AD"
020b42f8   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="Sunday"
020b4314   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="Monday"
020b4330   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="Tuesday"
020b434c   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="Wednesday"
020b436c   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="Thursday"
020b438c   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="Friday"
020b43a8   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="Saturday"
020b43c8   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Sun"
020b43dc   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Mon"
020b43f0   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Tue"
020b4404   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Wed"
020b4418   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Thu"
020b442c   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Fri"
020b4440   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Sat"
020b4454   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Su"
020b4468   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Mo"
020b447c   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Tu"
020b4490   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="We"
020b44a4   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Th"
020b44b8   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Fr"
020b44cc   70e2e918        18   System.String   STRVAL="Sa"
020b44e0   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="January"
020b44fc   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="February"
020b451c   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="March"
020b4534   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="April"
020b454c   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="May"
020b4560   70e2e918        22   System.String   STRVAL="June"
020b4578   70e2e918        22   System.String   STRVAL="July"
020b4590   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="August"
020b45ac   70e2e918        32   System.String   STRVAL="September"
020b45cc   70e2e918        28   System.String   STRVAL="October"
020b45e8   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="November"
020b4608   70e2e918        30   System.String   STRVAL="December"
020b4628   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Jan"
020b463c   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Feb"
020b4650   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Mar"
020b4664   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Apr"
020b4678   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Jun"
020b468c   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Jul"
020b46a0   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Aug"
020b46b4   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Sep"
020b46c8   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Oct"
020b46dc   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Nov"
020b46f0   70e2e918        20   System.String   STRVAL="Dec"
020b4704   70e3284c        84   System.Globalization.CalendarData
020b4758   70e2f46c        20   System.String[]
020b476c   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b477c   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b478c   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b479c   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b47ac   70e2f46c        16   System.String[]
020b47bc   70e2f46c        40   System.String[]
020b47e4   70e2f46c        40   System.String[]
020b480c   70e2f46c        40   System.String[]
020b4834   70e2f46c        64   System.String[]
020b4874   70e2f46c        64   System.String[]
020b48b4   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="zh-CHS"
020b48d0   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="zh-CHT"
020b48ec   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-DE"
020b4904   70e324e4        72   System.Globalization.CultureInfo
020b494c   70e3288c        28   System.Text.StringBuilder   STRVAL="de-de"
020b4968   70e2f320        22   System.Char[]
020b4980   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-de"
020b4998   70a04aec        48   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Globalization.CultureData, mscorlib]]
020b49c8   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b49e4   70e2fd14        28   System.RuntimeType
020b4a00   70e32a80        12   System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]
020b4a0c   70e32720       308   System.Globalization.CultureData
020b4b40   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-DE"
020b4b58   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-DE"
020b4b70   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-DE"
020b4b88   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="de-DE"
020b4ba0   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="zh-TW"
020b4bb8   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4bd0   70e2ecb8        12   System.Object
020b4bdc   70e30764        24   System.Int32[]
020b4bf4   70e32b8c        60   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Globalization.CultureData, mscorlib]][]
020b4c30   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4c48   70e324e4        72   System.Globalization.CultureInfo
020b4c90   70e3288c        28   System.Text.StringBuilder   STRVAL="en-us"
020b4cac   70e2f320        22   System.Char[]
020b4cc4   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-us"
020b4cdc   70e32720       308   System.Globalization.CultureData
020b4e10   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4e28   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4e40   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4e58   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="en-US"
020b4e70   70e2f320        16   System.Char[]
020b4e80   70e2f320        40   System.Char[]
020b4ea8   70e2e918        24   System.String   STRVAL="count"
020b4ec0   70e2e918        26   System.String   STRVAL="offset"
020b4edc   70e2f320        42   System.Char[]
020b4f08   70e2f320        42   System.Char[]
020b4f34   70e2f320        42   System.Char[]
020b4f60   70e2f320        44   System.Char[]
020b4f8c   70e2f320        42   System.Char[]
020b4fb8   70e2f320        38   System.Char[]
020b4fe0   70e2f320        40   System.Char[]
020b5008   70e2f320        38   System.Char[]
020b5030   70e2f320        86   System.Char[]
020b5088   70e2f320        66   System.Char[]
020b50cc   70e2ecb8        12   System.Object
391 objects, 16,415 bytes
Total GEN 0 size: 20,444 bytes
```

Comment: Use Lucida Console for the command prompt font. The default (Raster Fonts) is no good for that matter.

Comment: I will check the `.logopen /u` flag.